# How do I wire my new ceiling fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

This is the current wiring to the ceiling fixture.

If this wiring is OK, what wire goes where for my new fixture?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. I've edited your question to try to make it better fit our expected format here. Please [edit] again if I've messed up anything critical. It may help (actually, it will help a _lot_) if you'd include a picture of the wiring instructions of the new fixture, as well. Also, please search through the questions for each of the tags on this question to see if there's something that's close enough for you to figure this out on your own...

Comment: So, *next* time, take pictures before you diisconnect the original fixture. If the original fixture was working, then the new fixture should work if wired the same way.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like  normal old wiring for a ceiling light. You've got power coming in, and power going out and a switched hot controlled by a switch. Take your new fixture white wire and connect it to the smaller, white wire from the ceiling. Take the black wire from your new fixture and connect it to the larger, red wire from the ceiling. Make sure to turn off the power from the main panel, don't just turn off the switch. There won't be a ground wire up there so if your new fixture has a green or bare wire, coil it up there and forget about it.

Comment: Thank you Jack! I’ve never connected  to older wiring so I wasn’t certain.